# How to hide mouse on webApp SmartTv?

Tags: javascript, nginx, television, bind9

I'm trying to code a STB to Panasonic tv.
I have a vps with bind9 to resolve DNS and redirect the tv app to my web app, and a nginx server configured with some locations.

The donor app is wowtv, after I change the DNS server on tv, and open the app, appears a mouse.

I tested other STBs like http://player.clouddy.online and http://ott-play.com/f and the mouse don't appears.

What I need to do to Disable mouse?

I thought the JavaScript or css can do it  but nothing works!

Now I thing that must be a server configuration to solve it, I searched on internet but nobody has this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS rule

```
*, *:hover {
    cursor: none !important;
}
```

Comment: that's not it, I've tried using everything in css or JavaScript and it doesn't work, even with the mouse showing up I can't capture the keycodes events. I even copy the java script and css from the sites above and it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm thinking that the app(wowtv) understood that it's not the real app that is running. And thing that my webApp it's just a whatever site.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).